# Reasons that may cause a running process to voluntarily or involuntarily give-up the CPU?

Tags: process, cpu, process-management, thread, cpu-architecture

What are the reasons that may cause a running process to voluntarily or involuntarily give-up the CPU? As only one process can be running in the CPU/Core at any one time.

Comment: A process doesn't "give up" the CPU. A process gets CPU time from the scheduler.

Comment: Most usually the reason is making a blocking system call, such as an input-output operation, or waiting on a semaphore, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most system calls (essentially those that put the process on a queue for a service) result in the kernel scheduler taking the next most urgent process and making it run. Complicated slightly for multi-core, and where processes can be allocated to specific cores or CPUs.

Processor time is also allocated in maximum time slots, and at each clock tick the scheduler checks if the current process has used up its whole time slice. If so, it is suspended (i.e. not returned from the tick interrupt) and its temporary nice value is increased, so it is further from the head of the schedule queue. This ensures that programs that do frequent I/O get lots of short time slots, and CPU hogs get a few long ones.

All that describes fairly early Unix systems (because I haven't been working at that level lately), but it probably has not changed greatly. You can't improve that much on the original design.